# Tensorflow save one of multiple sessions

Tags: python, tensorflow

Hi have a Python script where I instantiate two objects of a neural network class.
Each object defines its own session and provide methods for saving the graph.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os, shutil

class TestNetwork:

    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id

        tf.reset_default_graph()

        self.s = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2], name='s')
        w_initializer, b_initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer(0., 1.0), tf.constant_initializer(0.1)
        self.k = tf.layers.dense(self.s, 2, kernel_initializer=w_initializer,
                    bias_initializer=b_initializer, name= 'k')

        '''Defines self.session and initialize the variables'''
        session_conf = tf.ConfigProto(
            allow_soft_placement = True,
            log_device_placement = False)
        self.session = tf.Session(config = session_conf)
        self.session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())



    def save_model(self, output_dir):
        '''Save the network graph and weights to disk'''
        if os.path.exists(output_dir):
            # if provided output_dir already exists, remove it
            shutil.rmtree(output_dir)

        builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder(output_dir)
        builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(
            self.session,
            [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING],
            clear_devices=True)
        # create a new directory output_dir and store the saved model in it
        builder.save()


t1 = TestNetwork(1)
t2 = TestNetwork(2)


t1.save_model("t1_model")
t2.save_model("t2_model")
```

The error I get is

> TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: The name
>   'save/Const:0' refers to a Tensor which does not exist. The operation,
>   'save/Const', does not exist in the graph.

I read something saying that this error is due to `tf.train.Saver`.

Thus I added the following line at the end of the `__init__` method:

```
self.saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.global_variables(), max_to_keep = 5)
```

However I still get the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tf.reset_default_graph` will clear the default graph stack and resets the global default graph.

> NOTE: The default graph is a property of the current thread. This
>   function applies only to the current thread. Calling this function
>   while a tf.Session or tf.InteractiveSession is active will result in
>   undefined behavior. **Using any previously created tf.Operation or
>   tf.Tensor objects after calling this function will result in undefined
>   behavior.**

You should specify `Graph` separately, and define all of these in the corresponding graph scope.

```
def __init__(self, id):
    self.id = id

    self.graph = tf.Graph()
    with self.graph.as_default():
        self.s = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2], name='s')
        w_initializer, b_initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer(0., 1.0), tf.constant_initializer(0.1)
        self.k = tf.layers.dense(self.s, 2, kernel_initializer=w_initializer,
                    bias_initializer=b_initializer, name= 'k')
        init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

    '''Defines self.session and initialize the variables'''
    session_conf = tf.ConfigProto(
        allow_soft_placement = True,
        log_device_placement = False)
    self.session = tf.Session(config = session_conf,graph=self.graph)
    self.session.run(init)
```

`tf.train.Saver` is another way to save model variables.

**Edit**
If you get empty "variable", you should save model in graph:

```
def save_model(self, output_dir):
    '''Save the network graph and weights to disk'''
    if os.path.exists(output_dir):
        # if provided output_dir already exists, remove it
        shutil.rmtree(output_dir)

    with self.graph.as_default():
        builder = tf.saved_model.builder.SavedModelBuilder(output_dir)
        builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(
            self.session,
            [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING],
            clear_devices=True)
        # create a new directory output_dir and store the saved model in it
        builder.save()
```

Comment: Thank you, with your fix it works, but the saved model directory contains an empty "variable" subdirectory thus I get an error: 
The passed save_path is not a valid checkpoin